# Can't run org.antlr.v4.Tool from terminal inside Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal, antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR in my project, I have Makefile that contains such lines:

```
JAVAC=javac
JAVAC_FLAGS=-sourcepath .
JAVA=java
JAVA_FLAGS=
PARSER=${JAVA} ${JAVA_FLAGS} org.antlr.v4.Tool
PARSER_FLAGS=-lib Syntax/normal -package Syntax.normal
LEXER=${JAVA} ${JAVA_FLAGS} org.antlr.v4.Tool
LEXER_FLAGS=-lib Syntax/normal -package Syntax.normal
all : test

Syntax/normal/normalLexer.java : Syntax/normal/normalLexer.g4
    ${LEXER} ${LEXER_FLAGS} Syntax/normal/normalLexer.g4
```

The last line converts to the:

`java  org.antlr.v4.Tool -lib Syntax/normal -package Syntax.normal Syntax/normal/normalLexer.g4`

When I run Makefile from the **Intellij Idea** then this java call gives error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.v4.Tool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.Tool
```

But in the same time, when I use default terminal to run this command, it executes perfectly:

[image]

Also if I use default system terminal to run `make` command, it runs without errors. But inside Inteliji Idea's terminal it gives me error.

The main question is: why terminal inside Intellij Idea can not run the same command as default system terminal?

Comment: _"why terminal inside Intellij Idea can not run the same command as default system terminal?"_ - Because it doesn't have the same classpath?

Comment: Try using the "-jar <full-path-to-antl4-complete.jar>".

Comment: Your Terminal might configure the `CLASSPATH` environment variable but this environment variable doesn't exist in the environment that the IDEA tries to run your makefile for some reason. Try using the IDE main menu `Run | Edit Configuration`, find your makefile configuration, configure a `CLASSPATH` environment variable there. Or make sure that you have configured the `CLASSPATH` in a shell initialization script  (not just `export` it temporarily in the Terminal) and restart the IDE to let it load this environment variable to see if it helps.